# How to apply lazy loading in flatlist in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, lazy-loading, react-native-flatlist

What is the best possible way to apply lazy load in Flatlist in react native.
Currently there is infinite scroll in the flatlist.
I am new to React native so i dont have any idea.

Comment: Usually peoples listen to `onScrollEnd` event and when it fired send request to server, then just update your data and that's all

Comment: could you find a way of lazy loading?

Answer (score 31):

You should use

```
<FlatList ....
onEndReached={this.endReached}
onEndReachedThreshold={.7}
.../>
```

the `onEndReached`: Called once when the scroll position gets within onEndReachedThreshold of the rendered content.

and `onEndReachedThreshold`: How far from the end (in units of visible length of the list) the bottom edge of the list must be from the end of the content to trigger the onEndReached callback. Thus a value of 0.5 will trigger onEndReached when the end of the content is within half the visible length of the list.

E.g:

```
class YourClass extends Component {
  state = { list: [], offset: 0, limit: 100 };
  componentDidMount() {
      this.fetchResult();
  }
    fetchResult = () => {
        const { offset, limit, list } = this.state;
        fetchModeDateFromAPI(offset, limit).then(res => {
        if (!res.list) return;
        this.setState({
            list: list.concat(res.list),
            offset: offset + 100,
            limit: limit
        });
        });
    };
    render = () => {
        return (
        <FlatList
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            extraData={this.state}
            onEndReached={this.fetchResult}
            onEndReachedThreshold={0.7}
            data={this.state.list}
            renderItem={rowData => {}}
            keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
        />
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't "limit" be a constant integer and only offset should change? If I am not mistaking your code would fetch more and more list items with each call and would start to fetch copies of previous items. First 100 is fetched with offset 0, second call would fetch additional 200 items with offset 100, third call fetches 300 items with offset 200 (but items from 200 to 300 were already fetched in second call) etc...?

Comment: for offset use: this.state.list + 1. So that each time you can fetch new data from server.