# React native flatlist feel so slow when List contain Images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I use 64x64 image for avater.it was very tiny size. by My app frame drop to 25-35 fps when scrool.
How can I optimize flatList image.?

```
  <FlatList
        data={this.props.data}
        extraData={{}}
        keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
        renderItem={this._renderItem}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
        ListHeaderComponent={
          <CommentsTextInput $comments={this.props.$comments} />
        }
        stickyHeaderIndices={[0]}
        initialNumToRender={5}
        removeClippedSubviews={true}
        updateCellsBatchingPeriod={25}
        windowSize={11}
      />
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49648292/how-to-apply-lazy-loading-in-flatlist-in-react-native

Answer (score 2):

You can use **getItemLayout** prop to reduce the workload the list does when scrolling
https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#getitemlayout

Ensuring images are cached will help.  does this to an extent, but you may find using a like like **react-native-fast-image** increases performance here (warning - be careful with this lib though and it can have memory issues -  make sure you profile to make sure it is working as expected)
https://github.com/DylanVann/react-native-fast-image

Avoid additional renders for your list items. Use **PureComponent** for class based components, or **memo** for functional ones.
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo

Use **keyExtractor** or add your keys carefully, without repeats to ensure that react can optimise changes to your list.

Answer (score 0):

For android devices, I have used resizeMethod="resize" to overcome this problem. Hope it helps!